# Fullscreen при смене одного Activity на другое Activity

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать приложение на полный экран (для всех активити).
Создал абстрактный FullscreenActivity и наследую от него остальные активити.

```
public abstract class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    private void showSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Возникли следующие проблемы:

1. При смене активити ненадолго появляется и скрывается ActionBar и NavigationBar (мелькает);
2. При загрузке приложения мгновение виден ActionBar и NavigationBar  (мелькает).

Как это поправить? И вообще правильный ли я способ выбрал с наследованием класса?

Пытаюсь реализовать через тему в манифесте

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Но тут не выходит скрыть NavigationBar

Comment: Я бы вам посоветовал откорректировать заголовок, не очень понятно при смене чего должен быть FullScreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать абстрактный класс таким, должно помочь:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Или вы можете сделать это через свой `AndroidManifest.xml` файл:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Если вы используете `AppCompatActivity`, вам нужно задать тему, как показано ниже.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868052

Comment: Почти вышло, но проблема с Navigation bar осталась, я дописал в вопросе

Comment: Перенёс код по скрытию NagivationBar в onResume и всё получилось

Comment: какие-то костыли пишите...

Comment: тему создайте без баров и ставьте в манифест. мелькать ничего не должно так как андроид до отрисовки уже знает что активити будет в фуллскрин

Comment: без action bar получилось, а способ убрать navigation bar не нашёл (обновил вопрос)